# Alloc class instance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I Have this class:

```
@class UIImagePicker;

@protocol UIImagePickerDelegate<NSObject>
@required

- (void)didFinishChooseImage:(UIImagePicker *)picker withImage:(UIImage*)img;

@end

@interface UIImagePicker : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
    UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
}

@property (assign) int type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <UIImagePickerDelegate> delegate;
```

And this is how i am alloc the `imgPicker`:

```
-(void)showImagePicker{
    imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imgPicker.delegate = self;

    //Trigger get photo from library function
    if (self.type == 0) {
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    } else {
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
}
```

And this is how i release the `imgPicker`:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [imgPicker release],imgPicker = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Did the release in the dealloc is ok? or i need to add another release because the imgPicker is with retain property??

Comment: once ok, but will be good to write self.imgPicker = nil;

Comment: Can `showImagePicker` be called multiple times before `dealloc`? Otherwise you are overwriting one that has a retain count with a new one without releasing it.

Comment: I don'think you should release two times.your method is right here

Comment: Looks fine to me. What is your problem?

Comment: I would recommend that since you go to the trouble of declaring `imgPicker` as a property you access it through `self.imgPicker` except when alloc'ing and releasing.

Comment: Maybe you could use ARC. This would save you a lot of trouble.